# How to create a purchase order in quickbook v3 PHP api

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

I am using quickbook v3. I've downloaded [PHP SAMPLE](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/SampleApp-PHP-for-OpenId-OAuth-V3APICalls) code from github and is runing well. It creates employee with ease but it's not creating a purchase order.

Here's what I've did so far..

```
$linedet = new IPPPurchaseOrderItemLineDetail();
$linedet->CustomerRef  = 86;

$line = new IPPLine();
$line->Id = 0;
$line->Description = 'test purchase order';
$line->Amount = 2.00;
$line->DetailType= 'ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail ';
$line->ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail = $linedet;
$line->BillableStatus = 'Notbillable';
$line->ItemRef = '2';
$line->UnitPrice = '25';
$line->Qty = '1';

$purchaseOrder = new IPPPurchaseOrder();
$purchaseOrder->Line = $line;
$purchaseOrder->VendorRef = 85;
$purchaseOrder->APAccountRef = 1;
$purchaseOrder->TotalAmt = 200.00;
$result = $dataService->Add($purchaseOrder); //add purchase order
```

I get the following error when I run the above code

```
Fatal error: Uncaught IdsException: [0]: Argument Null Exception thrown in D:\xamp\htdocs\projectmanager\wp-content\plugins\quickbook-oauth\v3-php-sdk-2.0.5\DataService\DataService.php on line 312
```

While creating the purchase order through their [api explorer](https://developer.intuit.com/v2/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#?id=PurchaseOrder) also throws 400 error

Your help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Without knowing your line numbers it's hard to say what is not set, but the error should help.  There's an argument you are passing on line 312 in your code, but it is null and should not be.  What variable is being set on that line, and what is it supposed to be set to?

Comment: It looks like the 213 is in the SDK rather than there code.

Comment: @gabe3886 It's because the response body is empty and is throwing null exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was giving the wrong item reference to $line object and that's why it was throwing error. Now i can create the purchase order with ease.
I changed the itemRef to 19 and it worked like a charm

```
$line->ItemRef = '19';
```

Comment: Hello, Can you please help me to do the same?
I need to create multiple purchase orders for products from different vendors?

Comment: Hey, i still need help to create multiple purchase orders for products from different vendors?

Comment: @Priyajain Did you create items prior to creating purchase orders? Share your code [here](http://kopy.io)